# Docker compose: how to use the same user/group ids and names for containers that share a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to run Drupal in Docker using `docker-compose` for starting all the services involved, which are "db", "web", "php" and "drush", as described in http://www.drupaldocker.org/compose/04-networks.html

Containers "web", "php" and "drush" share the "files_volume" volume. One thing that I noticed is that despite the fact that containers "web" and "drush" both have user/group `www-data:www-data`, the user/group IDs actually differ. This might be a problem for services that do not run as `root`, e.g. the Web server, which obviously runs as user `www-data`. If I create some files from the "drush" container as user `www-data:www-data`, such files will have UID/GID incompatible with the `www-data:www-data` on the "web" container and vice versa, and the files will potentially be inaccessible to the service. What should I do?

I would imagine that when defining a multi-container application with Docker compose, you could be able to define some "common" user shared by all or some of the containers in order to access the shared files in a uniform manner. Does anybody have experience solving this issue? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to define a common user. But you can set explicitly a user for every service/container. This is how you define a user in a docker compose file: https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15
And here are some details to users in docker containers:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user

Comment: @adebasi : thanks! That’s pretty much what I found so far. I wonder if some user namespace mapping or other magic can be used to overcome this issue? Because I mean it looks pretty normal to have the `www-data` user known to all the containers that work with `/var/www/html` directory...

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose ? Are you actually using UID / user option in its definition ?